# PHP Uncaught TypeError: array_merge(): Argument #1 must be of type array, null given

Tags: php, wordpress, typeerror, php-8, divi

Hello and thanks for your help. When running upgrading from PHP 7.4 to 8 I am running into this error "Uncaught TypeError: array_merge(): Argument #1 must be of type array, null given in Membership.php(30):" This is a Divi module and extends their page builder https://www.elegantthemes.com/documentation/developers/divi-module/how-to-create-a-divi-builder-module/. How is this not returning as an array? Is it a syntax issue? I am stuck and hoping someone can provide some insight. I am assuming since it works with PHP 7.4 and not 8 that I am just missing something. Thank you.

```
<?php

class Membership extends ET_Builder_Module {

  public $slug       = 'hello_membership';
  public $vb_support = 'on';
  private $api;

  protected $module_credits = array(
    'module_uri' => '',
    'author'     => 'Hello',
    'author_uri' => 'https://hello.com',
  );

  public function init() {
    $this->name = esc_html__( 'Hello Membership', 'hello_membership' );
  }

  public function get_fields() {

  }

  public function render( $attrs, $content = null, $render_slug ) {
    $tenant_url = get_option( 'hello_ticketure_tenant' );

    return '<div id="afp-membership" data-tenant-url="' . $tenant_url . '"></div>';
  }
}

new Membership;
```

Comment: How should that be a "syntax error"? The error message is crystal clear. It is not a syntax error but  a runtime error: an unexpected type of data is handed over to that function. So the question you need to answer is: why is that data missing?

Comment: I do not know about the details of that framework. But what strikes me odd here is the method `getFields()` which does not return something plural like (like an array) as one would expect as "fields", but _`null`_ ...

Comment: Apologies for the terminology. Is it possible that since `get_fields()` is returning nothing it is causing the TypeError?

Comment: That is what I tried to suggest. But as said: I do not know that framework nor your setup, so it is just a guess from my side. What about changing it to `return [];` ? Just for a test?

Comment: Welp. I added `return array();` to `get_fields()` and the error is gone! Appreciate your comments. `public function get_fields() {
    return array();
  }`

Comment: You had to use `return array();` instead of `return [];`? Otherwise you got a syntax error? That means you are using a totally outdated php version, are you aware of that?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `return array();` to `get_fields()` fixes the error. You need to explicitly tell it that it is returning an array. `public function get_fields() {     return array();   }`

Comment: Well yes, you need to "tell" a method that it should return an array. Indeed. How did you expect it should guess that by itself? ;-)